# Counting and cleansing

Tags: commentaries, parashat-metzora, zav-zava

VaYikra/Leviticus 15:2-3 
*Speak unto the children of Israel, and say unto them: When any man hath an issue out of his flesh, his issue is unclean. And this shall be his uncleanness in his issue: whether his flesh run with his issue, or his flesh be stopped from his issue, it is his uncleanness*.

What kind of issue(s) are these?

And afterwards when one is cleansed from the issue one should count seven days, and on the eight day bring a sacrifice (verse 13 and 14).

Should one from whom the flow of seed goeth out, so that he is unclean thereby, also count? Or is it only for an issue?

Comment: In your final question "one from whom the flow of seed goeth out etc." are you referring to verse 16?

Comment: Are you asking for the **physical** difference between a Zav emission  (who needs 7 days + sacrifice) and regular emissions (who needs to dip and wait for nightfall)?

Comment: @DannySchoemann I'm comparing verse 2 to 16

Comment: @JoelK Yes verse 16 in comparison to verse 2

Comment: @Levi Verse 16 is pretty clear that there is no requirement to count 7 days in that case. One immerses and is pure in the evening. The counting is only for an issue.

Comment: @JoelK just checking, because both men and woman have to count for certain things, but this passage of seed is right between them..